# Failing to run docker compose up

Tags: docker

I have a docker-compose.yml file to build and start the containers. It works on my MacBook fine but as soon as I run the docker compose file on my Ubuntu server it throws this error.

```
Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/buildx_buildkit_thirsty_joliot0" is already in use by container "". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

I did not make any change to the file and just running

`docker compose up` command. It still runs fine on my MacBook but causes this issue on both Ubuntu 20 and 22 server.

Comment: Have you checked if there is any stopped container of the same name?